# Incorrect return on binary to dec converter

Tags: java, constructor, binary, decimal, converters

Fixing up and tidying the converter when I noticed that it somehow gives out incorrect conversions.

For example, when creating a new number to convert using `BinaryNumber bn1 = new BinaryNumber("1011");` and then asking it to give out a result with `System.out.println(bn1.convertToDecimal());` it prints out 3 instead of the correct result of 11.

I'm almost sure I got the actual conversion wrong but going through it in my head I can't find the mistake.

```
public class BinaryNumber {
    private String n;

    public BinaryNumber(String pn) {
        n = pn;
    }

    public String getN() {
        return n;
    }

    // Creating the .convertToDecimal()
    public int convertToDecimal() {
        int bitPosition = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = n.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(2, bitPosition) * (n.charAt(i) - 48);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // Creating the .add to add the two different binary numbers after
    // converting
    public int add(BinaryNumber bn2) {
        return convertToDecimal() + bn2.convertToDecimal();
    }

    // Creating the .sub to subtract the two different binary numbers after
    // converting
    public int sub(BinaryNumber bn2) {
        return convertToDecimal() - bn2.convertToDecimal();
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't incremented your bit position

Comment: Why not use `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` and `Integer.parseInt(int, 2)`? You return an `int`.

Comment: Why not use `1 << bitPosition` (the left-bitshift operator) ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increment your bitposition variable.

> int bitPosition = 0;
>         int sum = 0;
>
> ```
>   for (int i = n.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
>
>     sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(2, bitPosition++) * (n.charAt(i) - 48);
>
>   }
>   return sum;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java has a built in binary system, using the primitive `int` type. You can use this by putting `0b` before the number in binary form.

If you are doing this for learning purposes, then here's what's happening:
On each iteration, the value of `bitPosition` is always `0`, because you never update it. Of course, you want to increase it with each iteration. This can be done simply by changing

`Math.pow(2, bitPosition)`

to

`Math.pow(2, bitPosition++)`

with the `++` after the variable to change it after it is referenced.